# Javascript click event fired twice, already stopping proagation

Tags: javascript

I have a very very strange problem, but I can't replicate it here, because I can't track down what is generating it, and it's part of a 200+ lines JS file, I will try to explain it at my best:

My problem is regarding DOM manipulation, I'm only using vanilla JavaScript.

I have an element `A`, when you click on it, a function is triggered to show the content of a div, I'm simply using `addEventListener('click', function(){ ... }, false)`.
It works.

On the same page, I have a similar situation, `B`. Here the problem: once I clicked for the first time on `B`, every time I click on `A`, the click element is fired twice.
I have searched on google, but the only results I found were talking about the need of stopping the event propagation.

I'm already doing so.

What makes it strange, is that the problem exist only once I clicked for the first time on `B`, otherwise it works perfectly.

Any idea? Please ask any question needed to better understand the problem.

Comment: `but I can't replicate it here,` then it's going to be pretty hard for anybody to help you. The first step in debugging the problem should be to try and find the smallest possible example that replicates the problem.

Comment: @MattBurland I know. The thing is, what is causing the problems? I have tried everything, using the Chrome Dev tools, I have seen that the click event is generated on the exact same element both times. It acts like a true double-click.

Comment: Include a link to your code? Something like GitHub, or JSFiddle?

Comment: crazy thought but, do you by any chance attach the event listener twice? it will sound weird but, do you include the script on the page only once, right?

Comment: other than that, event propagation seems the only logical explanation... as long as we don't see the source code

Comment: @StefanBaiu Double-checking on that. By the way, I'm commenting out code until the problem no longer exist, so I will be able to post here the "malitius" code

Comment: @Alberto: without any code, we can only guess. You aren't even telling us *where* you are attaching the event listener(s) or how the elements `A` and `B` are related. Start with some simplified HTML with the same parent / child relationship and then attach event listeners one at a time until you see the problem reappear.

Comment: @StefanBaiu Ok, found it! I'm using angular, I was initializing the script like this: `$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded' ...`. When clicking on `B`, I was firing another include request, resulting in another initialization of the script! Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for the ideas in the comments. As @StefanBaiu suggested, the function was being initialized twice:

I'm using angular to include the content (it's a partial view), so I'm listening for the `$includeContentLoaded` event to initialize the function listening for the event.

When clicking on `B`, I was including new content, resulting in `$includeContentLoaded` being fired again.

How I solved the issue:

```
var pageIncluded = true; // When loading the controller

$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
  if (pageIncluded) {
     // Inizialize the function
     pageIncluded = false;
  }
}
```